# Postgres: How to forbird the use of SELECT * (star)

Tags: postgresql

The use of star in a query can come for sure handy, however it is a pain if many devs in a large organization are using it and rely on it.

Hence I'm wondering if we can forbid the use of * to all user (or certain users)

Comment: This is an easy one, you can't.

Comment: Why not physically removing the `*` from the keyboard? Sadly, using `select mytable from mytable` or `select row_to_json(mytable) from mytable` would remain available.

Comment: The only way to avoid the use of  SELECT "star", is to teach users not to do so by showing them concrete examples or it will hurt performance. This is the first thing I show in all my SQL lessons!

Comment: are there proxies such as envoy that have a good query parser/constraint checker that can achieve the same results?

Answer (score 0):

you cant, but there is the way =)

of course you can always teach and write letters to users by explaining why the cant do that, but thats not work for us ...

what we come up with this  -  to check by procedure the users with huge performance issues with their queries and than you can:

1. just kill by pid , but thats the evil things to do =). OR you can kill only the users that uses * in their queries. But we kill only with a huge date or in strange status.
2. you can send a letter to user (if of course users registered by email or LDAP and by LDAP than its possible to get the email)

[to check the statistics](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/monitoring-stats.html)

```
select * from pg_stat_activity;
```

Comment: so what you do is running every N seconds the query `select * from pg_stat_activity where statement LIKE "%*%"`?

Comment: maybe not in N seconds, but in minutes - that will do not harm. 
In our case it was one in 30 minutes, because we just seek for a long queries.